# Javascript Box to appear when any form fields have been edited

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has various fields to save to a database. How do I make an alert box appear if any of those fields have been edited?

Just to be sure, the alert box CANNOT open up IF the fields have not been touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually found the solution.

Insert into the head:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    var needToConfirm = false ;

    function Submit_Click() {
        needToConfirm = false; 
    }

    function setDirtyFlag() {
        needToConfirm = true; //Call this function if some changes is made to the web page and requires an alert
        // Of-course you could call this is Keypress event of a text box or so...
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    function confirmExit() {
        if (needToConfirm)
            return "You have attempted to leave this page. If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    }
</script>
```

Then within the body, the form looks like this:

```
<form onunload="confirmExit()">
    <p>
        <input id="Text1" type="text"  value ="jitesh" onchange="setDirtyFlag();" /></p>
    <p>
        <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onchange="setDirtyFlag();"/></p>
    <p>
        <input id="Radio1" checked="checked" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" onchange="setDirtyFlag();" /></p>
    <p>
        <input id="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click();"/></p>
    <p>&nbsp;
        </p>
</form>
```

We have to ensure that all fields that are applicable for that confirm box to appear must have the onchange answer of setDirtyFlag();

Answer (score 1):

create a flag, eg:

```
var formUpdated = false:
```

wire up an OnBlur or OnChange (depending on the type of form element, like textbox or checkbox) event to every form field

```
document.getElementById('#formelementId').onChange = function () {
    // check if the value has changed
    formUpdated = true;
}
```

wire up an event to the onsubmit of the form e.g:

```
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { 
      if(formUpdated){
         alert('the form was updated')
      }
  }
```

Comment: this looks like the closest solution - however, i would like a Confirm javascript box to appear when the user steers away from the page (ie. onbeforeunload) NOT via the submit button. The Confirm box should only appear to read something like 'Are you sure you don't want to save changes?'

Answer (score 0):

you can try reading up on `onchange` or `onblur`

Answer (score 0):

Try the [OnChange](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) event.

following is simple example,

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Example of onChange Event Handler</TITLE>

<SCRIPT>

function valid(input) {
    alert("You have changed the value from 10 to " + input);
}

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H3>Example of onChange Event Handler</H3>
Try changing the value from 10 to something else:<BR>
<FORM>
     <INPUT TYPE="text" VALUE="10" onChange="valid(this.value)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: this doesnt do the intended action as an alert box appears every time an onchange event occurs. I only want the aler box to appear when you'r exiting the page (ie. beforepageunload). would you happen to know the code for that?\